# Updating the properties of the Model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an application of MVC in which i am defining my model as Album which is as follows:

```
public int AlbumId { get; set;}
public int GenersId { get; set; }
public int ArtistId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public String Price { get; set; }
public String AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
public Geners Geners { get; set; }
public Artist Artist { get; set; }
```

in this model the GenersId was previously GenerId then i changed it to  GenersId .now in the index method its showing me an error as follows:

The model backing the 'MusicstoreEntity' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

MusicstoreEntity is the model Entity that i have created.
pls suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx.

You could either:

1. Delete your database and start again
2. Change your database initialiser
3. Enable migrations and write and generate a code migration
4. Enable migrations and use automatic migrations in your configuration

If you're just making lots of changes to your models during development, then you might be happy to delete your database everytime the model changes. You can do this by setting the database initialiser:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<MyContext>());
```

Have a look at http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm for more info.